# How to use SimpleDateFormat to format a string array

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm trying to format a String array of dates using SimpleDateFormat. It will correctly format the first entry, but claims the second is unparseable, even if they are identical. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here, any tips?

```
    String dates = "";
    String test = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    String end = "MMMMMMMMM d, yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(test);

    //Match the pattern of 1 or more digits, a backslash, one or more digits, 
    //a backslash, and then four digits
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+/\\d+/\\d\\d\\d\\d");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    //While there are matches, concatenate the match to the string dates,
    //with a semicolon separating each match
    while (matcher.find())
    {
        String a = matcher.group(0).toString();
        dates += ";" + a;
    }

    //Split the string on semicolons
    String[] inputString = dates.split(";");

    for (int i=1; i<inputString.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(inputString[i]);
    }

    //Change all dates of format MM/dd/yyyy into Month date, year and 
    //force them into uppercase
    for (int i=1; i<inputString.length; i++)
    {
        String old = inputString[i];
        Date a = sdf.parse(old);
        sdf.applyPattern(end);
        String notOld = sdf.format(a);
        inputString[i] = notOld;
        inputString[i] = inputString[i].toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(inputString[i]);
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
12/6/1852
12/6/1954
DECEMBER 6, 1852
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "12/6/1954"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at Info.fixer(Info.java:132)
at Info.main(Info.java:35)
```

Comment: `what is the variable input holding in the example???

Comment: For this snippet the text file simply holds:

"12/6/1852
12/6/1954"

on two lines. There is much more to the string as it's a long text file where I'm extracting dates, but these are being tested at the very top of the file, so it never gets past them.

Comment: When you call `applyPattern(end)`, you change `sdf` to format `MMMMMMMMM d, yyyy`. On next iteration, you try to parse `12/6/1954` using that format, and Oops!! That doesn't work.

Comment: Ahhh I see now. This is my first time using simpledateformat, I didn't notice that applyPattern() sets the sdf to the new format instead of just using it for that instance. Adding sdf.applyPattern(test) to the top of that loop fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Andreas' comment helped. I didn't know simpledateformat sets a format with applyPattern(), so it was using a different pattern for subsequent values. This change to the bottom looped fixed it:

```
for (int i=1; i<inputString.length; i++)
{
    sdf1.applyPattern(dmy);
    String old = inputString[i];
    Date a = sdf.parse(old);
    sdf.applyPattern(end);
    String notOld = sdf.format(a);
    inputString[i] = notOld;
    inputString[i] = inputString[i].toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(inputString[i]);
}
```